# Importing PyQt4.QtGui but not QtCore with PyCharm

Tags: python, pyqt4, pycharm, qtgui

My problem is that I can perfectly, in the ubuntu's terminal, type :

> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

There are no errors.I think it means that python3.4 has all the modules I want.
However, when I type those lines in PyCharm (with the 3.4python interpreter) it tells me :`QtGui is an unsolved reference`.

It drives me crazy. Any ideas about the problem ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made an error in the tittle I meant:  Can import PyQt4.QtGui but not QtCore with PyCharm. Sorry

Comment: Just import them on separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I used to prevent this was:

```
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui
import PyQt4.QtCore as QtCore
```